# SQL Query For Stocks of Items in Msny Warehouses

Tags: sql

Guys

I have three tables like down below.
[image]

I want to have a list of certain the amount of a certain item on every existing warehouse in the database like below

[image]

I'm not really good in database query, and so far I only get to show the data such as down below using join sentence. how can I achieve the desired output?

[image]

Comment: please read https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question and edit your question

Comment: and which rdms are you using please tag only one